# You have an error in your SQL syntax: MariaDB server + codeigniter + LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv, xampp, mariadb

I'm using codeigniter. Trying to load csv file into DB. `$path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/';`

The error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Institution ID Code,Acquiring Institution Name,Service Indicator,Local Point of ' at line 5

LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/fichier/test3.csv" INTO TABLE atm_location FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" IGNORE 0 LINES (Acquiring Institution ID Code,Acquiring Institution Name,Service Indicator,Local Point of Service ID,Country Code,Administrative Region, Tourist Area,City / Town / Locality,Postal Code,Address,Location Name,Type of Location,Type of Access,Opening Hours,Opening Days,Card Programm Indicator,Opening Date,GPS Latitude,GPS Longitude)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

This works:

```
$query = $this->db->query('LOAD DATA INFILE "'.$path.'fichier/test3.csv" INTO TABLE atm_location FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"');
```

This doens't work (give the error above):

```
$query = $this->db->query('
        LOAD DATA INFILE "'.$path.'fichier/test3.csv" 
        INTO TABLE atm_location FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" 
        LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" 
        IGNORE 0 LINES 
        (Acquiring Institution ID Code,Acquiring Institution Name,Service Indicator,Local Point of Service ID,Country Code,Administrative Region, Tourist Area,City / Town / Locality,Postal Code,Address,Location Name,Type of Location,Type of Access,Opening Hours,Opening Days,Card Programm Indicator,Opening Date,GPS Latitude,GPS Longitude)');
```

No columns missing. csv file don't have columns names. DB have columns names that are the same as write here. I'm working on localhost, with xampp obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume the issue is the whitespace in your column names:

```
    (Acquiring Institution ID Code,Acquiring Institution Name,Service Indicator,Local Point of Service ID,Country Code,Administrative Region, Tourist Area,City / Town / Locality,Postal Code,Address,Location Name,Type of Location,Type of Access,Opening Hours,Opening Days,Card Programm Indicator,Opening Date,GPS Latitude,GPS Longitude)'
```

Backtick them and try again:

```
 (`Acquiring Institution ID Code`,`Acquiring Institution Name` ....
```

In the future, avoid whitespace for column names.  Keeping the names all lowercase is good advice too.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know spaces were a problem and I did not know the existence of the \`. What is the difference between \` and ' ? Do they the same thing but allow imbrication ?

Comment: Bactick is the quote character for identifiers (table names, columns, etc...) in mysql. Single and double quote are used to quote values which are strings, characters, and string representation of time, and such

Comment: You can enable `ANSI_QUOTES` which will allow double quotes to also be identifier quotes, but don't do this, just stick to backticks.  it keeps it less confusing as you always know a backticked name is an identifier.  Also you can't guarantee your Query will work on a system with ansi quote turned off